# How to intepret the shape of the array in Python?

Tags: python

I am using a package and it is returning me an array. When I print the shape it is `(38845,)`. Just wondering why this ','.

I am wondering how to interpret this.

Thanks.

Comment: Gabriel: "shape" in context of multidimensional arrays is the size in each dimension. Thus, a 3x2x4 3D array of 24 elements will have a shape of (3, 2, 4).

Comment: @Gabriel, this is almost certainly using the Numpy terminology, it's not available by default in Python AFAIK.

Comment: @Bruno: Mathematics terminology, not specifically NumPy. It comes up wherever you're dealing with real multidimensional arrays (which few of the common modern languages do - they usually make do with nested 1D arrays, so "shape" is not well-defined).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python has tuples, which are like lists but of fixed size. A two-element tuple is `(a, b)`; a three-element one is `(a, b, c)`. However, `(a)` is just `a` in parentheses. To represent a one-element tuple, Python uses a slightly odd syntax of `(a,)`. So there is only one dimension, and you have a bunch of elements in that one dimension.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're using Numpy. If so, the shape `(38845,)` means you have a 1-dimensional array, of size 38845.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're talking of a Numpy array.

`shape` returns a tuple with the same size as the number of dimensions of the array. Each value of the tuple is the size of the array along the corresponding dimensions, or, as [the tutorial](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html#head-62ef2d3c0a5b4b7d6fdc48e4a60fe48b1ffe5006) says:

> An array has a shape given by the number of elements along each axis.

Here you have a 1D-array (as indicated with a 1-element tuple notation, with the coma (as @Amadan) said), and the size of the 1st (and only dimension) is 38845.
For example `(3,4)` would be a 2D-array of size 3 for the 1st dimension and 4 for the second.

You can check the documentation for `shape` here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html

Answer (score 0):

> Just wondering why this ','.

Because `(38845)` is the same thing as `38845`, but a tuple is expected here, not an int (since in general, your array could have multiple dimensions). `(38845,)` is a 1-tuple.